# Namespace alias in web.config not recognised by Resharper

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, namespaces, resharper

In my ASP.NET WebApplication I have the following entry in my web.config:

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="Static">
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="XSS=Microsoft.Security.Application" />
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

This enables me to use the AntiXSS-Library within my Pages and Controls in an easy and short way without using the fully qualified namespace every time, like this:

```
<%# XSS.Encoder.HtmlEncode(Eval("something").ToString()) %>
```

instead of

```
<%# Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(Eval("Branche_lbl").ToString()) %>
```

This works perfectly in ASP.NET, unfortunately Resharper seems to be unable to resolve the alias, marks the line as error and says

> Cannot resolve symbol: XSS

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's seems like a hack of ASP.NET and not documented...
We'll think about fix in R# 7.0

Answer (score 0):

If it compiles fine and works, you *could* just have Resharper ignore it by going into the "Inspection Options".